# Disable form submit button if all input and textarea are empty except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to enable a submit button only when each input fields has a value except one. The except one.

**HTML:**

```
// start of form
<input type='text /> // cant be blank
<input type='text /> // cant be blank
<input type='text /> // cant be blank
<textarea type='text /> // cant be blank
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
// end of form
<input id='subscription-input' type='text /> // exclude this one only
[...]
```

JS:

```
function doCheck(){
  var allFilled = true;
  $('input[type=text]').not('#subscription-input').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
          return false;
      }
  });
  if (allFilled) {
    // Apply active css and enable button
    $('button[type=submit]').removeClass('form-submit--plain').addClass('form-submit--active');
    $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !allFilled);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').keyup(doCheck).focusout(doCheck);
});
```

Basically I need a way to get the `textarea` field so I thought adding wilecard (`*`) would work:

```
$('*[type=text]').not('#subscription-input').each(function(){...}
```

How to get the `input` and `textarea` fields?

Comment: Initially keep you button as disable Use validator plugin, set your validation rules and hook your button enable script in its validate success method.

Comment: I think you should give a class on the fields where you need the validation should fire and active the button.

Comment: use $.trim(....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the same class to all the fields and attach event to that class with a `not` for the ID:

```js
function doCheck() {
  var allFilled = true;
  $('.form-fields:not(#subscription-input)').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      allFilled = false;
    }
  });

  $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !allFilled);
  if (allFilled) {
    $('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  doCheck();
  $('.form-fields').keyup(doCheck);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='form-fields' />
<input type='text' class='form-fields' />
<input type='text' class='form-fields' />
<textarea class='form-fields'></textarea>
<input id='subscription-input' class='form-fields' type='text' />
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

change code to:

```
function doCheck(){
  var allFilled = true;
  $('input[type=text]:not(#subscription-input),textarea').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
          allFilled=false;
      }
  });
  if (allFilled) {
    // Apply active css and enable button
    $('button[type=submit]').removeClass('form-submit--plain').addClass('form-submit--active');
    $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !allFilled);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').keyup(doCheck).focusout(doCheck);
});
```

Comment: Button enables now when first input has value.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/ehjxvz4j/1/

```js
function doCheck(){
  var allFilled = true;
  $('input[type=text]').not('#subscription-input').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
          allFilled = false;
      }
  });
  if($('textarea').val() == ''){
   allFilled = false;
  }
  if (allFilled) {
    // Apply active css and enable button
    $('button[type=submit]').removeClass('form-submit--plain').addClass('form-submit--active');
  } 
  $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !allFilled);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text], textarea').focusout(doCheck);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' />
<textarea></textarea>
<button type='submit' disabled>Submit</button>

<input id='subscription-input' type='text'/>
```